# How do I install this theme?

Tags: lubuntu, themes

Just started using Lubuntu and wanted to customize it a bit.

I am trying to install [this theme](https://www.gnome-look.org/p/1013482/).

I tried everything I found on the internet like putting it in the `/usr/themes` directory or creating a `/home/[name-of-user]/.themes` directory and putting it there.

Comment: Try putting the theme files in /usr/share/themes (not /usr/themes).

Comment: See this: https://www.addictivetips.com/ubuntu-linux-tips/customize-the-lxde-desktop/

Comment: If the theme file ends in (.zip/.tar/ tar.gz) you first need to extract it. Open terminal and position yourself in the directory where the extracted them and write sudo mv (theme filename) /usr/share/themes . Mind spaces and capital letters in the theme filename.

Answer (score 0):

I think the directory /usr/themes/ should be ok. Now what you can do is 
Install unity-tweak-tool and you can check there if the theme is available and customize it.

Comment: I read that unity-tweak-tool isnt avilable anymore. Is that wrong?

Comment: OP uses **L**ubuntu, will Unity Tweak Tool work?